# Sorting list in java and looking for max percentage

Tags: java, list

In my task I need to sort list in Java but I only sorted list by population. In class City I also have number of obese people. How to return perctentage.

```
class CovidSorter implements Comparator<City> {

@Override
    public int compare(City o1, City o2) {
        Integer compareInt = o1.numberOfPeople().compareTo(o2.noOfPeople());
        return compareInt;
    }

}
```

Input:

> New York People: 10000000 Obese: 50000
>
> Seattle 200000 1500
>
> Las Vegas 2000000 12345
>
> ```
> New York: 0.5%
>
> Seattle: 0.75%
>
> Las Vegas: 0.61725%
> ```

So highest number has Seattle.

My problem is how to properly call it in main so sorter could work and implement (numberOfCitizens/obesePeople)*100. In my task I had set but I casted it to a list.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by implementing that logic inside your comparator:

```
cities.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(
            c -> ((double) c.getNumberOfPeople() / c.getObesePeople()) * 100.0));
```

See [`Comparator.comparingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) docs for further details.

---

**EDIT:** As you say you need to do it inside your class, here's a way:

```
class CovidSorter implements Comparator<City> {

    @Override
    public int compare(City o1, City o2) {
        double p1 = ((double) o1.getNumberOfPeople() / o1.getObesePeople()) * 100.0;
        double p2 = ((double) o2.getNumberOfPeople() / o2.getObesePeople()) * 100.0;
        return Double.compare(p1, p2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I need to do that in my class:

Comment: Integer compareInt = (o1.getNoOfCitizens()/(float)o1.noOfObese())*100). COMPARE here wont work

Answer (score 1):

I made 2 local variables and then just compared them:

```
  public int compare(City o1, City o2) {
    float max1= (float) ((o1.getNoOfObese() / (float)o1.getNoOfCitizens()) * 100.0);
    float max2= (float) ((o2.getNoOfObese() / (float)o2.getNoOfCitizens()) * 100.0);

   if(max1>max2)
       return 1;
   else if(max1<max2)
       return -1;
   else
       return 0;
```

But Comparator.comparingDouble is simplier way but my taks was to made it in class. Thank you for your help :D